# Excel InitialFileName Not Working With Period

Tags: excel, vba

In the document I have a button to do a save as, this function takes a path and creates the filename based off a cell and the date.  This has been working fine until a path came up that has a period in it, it will locate the path correctly but is no longer filling in the filename.

```
Sub SaveWorkbookAsNewFile()
    Dim NewFileType As String
    Dim NewFile As String
    Dim newfilename As String
    Dim cellname As String
    Dim monthnum As String
    Dim monthtxt As String
    Dim daynum As String
    Dim yearnum As String
    Dim yeartxt As String
    Dim SaveArea As String
    Dim q As Long

    If Worksheets.Count <= 6 Then MsgBox "You must run the report before saving it.", vbInformation, "Save Error": End

    SaveArea = Sheet1.Range("K12")
    cellname = Sheet1.Range("K20")

    '********************************************************************
    Dim objFSO As Object, objFolder As Object, objSubFolder As Object
    Dim varDirectory As Variant
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim strDirectory As String, goodfolder As String
    Dim NumMonth As Integer

    NumMonth = 0
    q = 0
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(SaveArea)

    NumMonth = Month(Date)

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders

        If InStr(1, UCase(objSubFolder.Name), UCase(MonthName(NumMonth, True)), vbTextCompare) > 1 Then goodfolder = objSubFolder.Name: Exit For

    Next objSubFolder

    If Not goodfolder = "" Then SaveArea = SaveArea & goodfolder & "\"


    '********************************************************************

    monthnum = Month(Date)
    monthtxt = UCase(MonthName(monthnum, True))
    daynum = Day(Date)
    yearnum = Year(Date)
    yeartxt = Right(yearnum, 2)

    newfilename = cellname & "-" & monthtxt & "-" & daynum & "-" & yeartxt

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False    ' Prevents screen refreshing.

    NewFileType = "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm," & _
               "All files (*.*), *.*"

    NewFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
        InitialFileName:=SaveArea & newfilename, _
        fileFilter:=NewFileType)

    If NewFile <> "" And NewFile <> "False" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=NewFile, _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, _
            CreateBackup:=False, _
            ConflictResolution:=xlUserResolution
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

A working path (SaveArea) is as follows: `\\TestServer\Test\Test\Standards\Test\Test 1\`

A broken path (SaveArea) is as follows: `\\TestServer\Test\Test\Standards\Test\Test. 1\`

Both bring up the save as dialog, but the path with the period does not populate a filename. Is there a way to make this work when the path includes a period?

Edit: I've found a similar post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1257977/software-excel-vba-not-populating-default-file-name-in-saveas-dialog-box) but it doesn't have a solution to fix the problem.

Comment: Question.. Is there actually a space between the `Test` and the `1` , and thus the `Test.` and the `1` as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this to work, add the file extension to the InitialFileName parameter like below:

```
NewFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    InitialFileName:=SaveArea & newfilename & ".xlsm", _
    fileFilter:=NewFileType)
```